# How to add SwipeListener to list Item using cursor Adapter

Tags: android, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to add left and right swipe to `listview` for creating calling intent and messaging intent like contacts app :
swipe right -> call
swipe left -> message

OnSwipe, it should call an intent

I'm trying lot of ways to do i'm unable get the solution

Here is my code below for spanning list View items(excluding swipe related code because i use libraries till now):

This is my adpater class

```
class ContactCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

public ContactCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
    ImageView profilePictureView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_person);

    int columnNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_PERSON_NAME);
    int columnNumberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_CONTACT_NUMBER);
    int profilePictureIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactEntry.COLUMN_PROFILE_PICTURE);

    String contactName = cursor.getString(columnNameIndex);
    final String contactNumber = cursor.getString(columnNumberIndex);
    byte[] profilePicture = cursor.getBlob(profilePictureIndex);

    if (contactName.length() == 0) {
        nameTextView.setText(contactNumber);
    } else {
        nameTextView.setText(contactName);
    }
    if (profilePicture != null) {
        if (profilePicture.length > 3) {
            profilePictureView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(profilePicture, 0, profilePicture.length));
        } else {
            profilePictureView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my contact list item file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_color">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_person"
        android:layout_width="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_person"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_person"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to use `CursorAdapter` only

Comment: then use `GestureDetector`, also use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead of custom `CursorAdapter`, much simpler

Comment: Please help me @pskink, how to use `GestureDetector` for swiping left and right `listview`

Comment: create a detector `new GestureDetector(context, gestureListener)` and feed it with `TouchEvent`s - more: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect

Comment: Thank you @pskink but how can i add different color on swipe(right swipe -green and left swipe yellow)